# Result file shows values that are not part of element matches

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

Using XSLT3.0, I am parsing a JSON file using "json-to-xml" which results in a XML map. As second step I create an element, add namespace prefix and assign attributes. I have intentionally added more data in the JSON file, than the template that matches "ix_hidden".

**Question:**

Why does the output file contains the 2 values from JSON object "Other", if I do not have a template that matches "Other"?

**Assumptions:**

I do understand that the first template transform the complete node called "data", thus the parsed result in terms of XML map, contains the element "Other" and its childs.

My assumption so far is that the the XSL file acts as a firewall between source file and output file, meaning that nothing should pass through unless there is a given template that matches the specified expression pattern (in templates match attribute value). If matched, everything inside of template is executed.

Would you be kind of clarify above concern and potentially show a code correction to secure that all unmatched data in XSL, is being exluded from the output?

The XSLT fiddle is down so this time I just post the code below:

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{
  "ix_hidden": {
    "CompanyName": "Company Limited",
    "OrganisationNumber": "123"
  },

  "Other": {
    "Milk": 2,
    "Water": 5
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Attribute-sets -->

  <xsl:attribute-set name="ix-hidden">
    <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">period0</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML, results in XML map -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xbrli:xbrl>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
      </xbrli:xbrl>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Create IX hidden element  -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'ix_hidden']//*[@key and not(*)]">
      <xsl:element name="ix:{@key}" use-attribute-sets="ix-hidden">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/1" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/2">
  <ix:CompanyName contextRef="period0">Company Limited</ix:CompanyName>
  <ix:OrganisationNumber contextRef="period0">123</ix:OrganisationNumber>
  25
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

**Expected result:**

Only execution of matched templates should occure, thus the values 2 and 5 prior to closing tag "xbrli:xbrl" should not be visible. This expectation is also valid if JSON data content should be expanded with other nodes that does not have matched templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the built-in template rules.

In XSLT 3.0, the default is `text-only-copy`.

Take a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-rule.

One option is to add:

```xml
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

"My assumption so far is that the the XSL file acts as a firewall between source file and output file, meaning that nothing should pass through unless there is a given template that matches the specified expression pattern (in templates match attribute value)."

That assumption, I'm afraid, is totally wrong.

In XSLT 3.0 you can define a number of policies for handling unmatched items using `<xsl:mode on-no-match="..."/>`. The default policy is to copy data from the source to the result. Alternative options include dropping the data from the output, or throwing an error.